# Efficient value selection from Array

Tags: c#

I have a array that contains some values like

- 250
- 500
- 1000
- 2000

Example :

I want to mix milk based on asked volume.
Some one asks 2800 ml milk.

To able to reach this volume I want 2000ml and 1000ml package from the array. This the most efficient one. You also could select 6 x 500ml package but it's more work.

The logic is to use the least packages as possible with least possible spillage.

I wrote the following code. It seems to work but need to test it bit more. Maybe it's not the most efficient code but it seems to work. Any code optimizations are welcome and also couldn't answer my own question because the question was closed.

```
List<int> packages = new List<int>() { 250,500,1000,2000 };

        //packages = new List<int>(packages.OrderByDescending(x => x));

        int wantedVolume = 2800;
        int leftover = wantedVolume;

        List<int> selectedpackages = new List<int>();

        while(true)
        {
            var nearest = packages.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs((long)x - leftover)).First();

            selectedpackages.Add(nearest);
            leftover = leftover - nearest;

            if (selectedpackages.Sum() >= wantedVolume)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("");

        foreach (int i in selectedpackages)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You need a package of " + i + "ml");
        }
```

If the needed volume is 1750 ml the code will select 2000ml package from array. That would be less handling but it will spill 250ml. The efficient selection would be 1000ml + 500ml + 250ml

With needed volume of 2300 it will select

2000ml
250ml
250ml

But efficient with handling would be

2000ml
500ml

The spillage is the same.

Comment: You haven't explained the rules to select items from the array, just provided two examples.

Comment: @TimSchmelter  The explanation is the rule.

Comment: Yes, but there is no explanation. You've shown a small sample and told us what you want as result. But the logic is not clear at all.

Comment: 2000 + 1000 = 3000 not 2800. Explain better why you would select 2000 and 1000 for the given value 2800

Comment: Do you mean the smallest matching sum bigger than the value (2800 in your example)?

Comment: Also if you're trying to get the closest possible value, 2000 + 3 x 250 = 2750 which is closer to 2800 than 3000 is.

Comment: The nearest value doenst need to match exacht. Exact is only when it is possible to match it exact.

Comment: 2750 is nearer to 2800 than 3000

Comment: Can it be a multiple of a value or only a sum of all available values? The 6 x 500 = 3000 example suggests the former, but is it correct? If yu have multiple nearest, what do you want?

Comment: I'm guessing this is going to turn out to be an NP-Complete problem.

Comment: @Matthias You are right. That's why I ask the question here. The nearest would be 2750 but to able to reach tha input value you need more then what is asked.

Comment: @Shift So you are looking for the smallest output that is bigger or equal to the input?

Comment: Are the higher values always a multiple of the smaller ones?

Comment: @MatthewWatson this is basically the [change-making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem), so yeah, it is.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Ok. Otherwise I think you have to go though all possible combinations in order to find the "nearest" one.

Comment: @Shift: have you considered that also the "arrogant high reps" wanted to help? Otherwise they wouldn't have spent their time here. But it's a waste of time if someone provides a fairly complex requirement with very little informations and no own effort so far.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That doesn't go for all high rep guys.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Shift Just a reminder: high rep guys got their high rep from helping people. You've made significant improvements to phrase the question clearly, which is great, but please also show your best attempt to solve it (any code would be better than nothing, honestly). If you can do that the question would be likely reopened and even some of the downvotes reversed as well.

Comment: If you clarify the question I should think it could be reopened: I think what you're asking is: `"How do I determine the smallest number of items that can be combined to equal or exceed the target amount. Individual items can be selected multiple times"` - is that correct?

Comment: Are you allowed to have a total that is under the target amount? For example, the nearest combination above a target of 1000 might be 1100, and the nearest combination below it might be 999 (assuming that the target cannot be reached exactly). Since 999 is closer to 1000, is that a valid solution? Or must the total be higher?

Comment: @MatthewWatson U have to use what's available in the array. That is 250-500-1000-2500. If some one asks you i waht 2800ml milk you have to get 1 x 2 liter pack and 1 liter pack to able to give him the needed volume. The logic is to use at least packages as possible.

Comment: I think the question is clear enough now, and I've voted to reopen it. (However, if it doesn't get reopened, you might want to consider deleting this one and creating a new one.)

Comment: ok so you got the basics..now you just need to add a layer... not just find first value that matches ie 1000 500 etc So put these acceptable working values into list and then pick best (add logic)..if you prefer 2000 500 instead of 2000 250 250 then you have to build in this logic.   You may have to build a permutations routine to work out how each order can be built up... then pick which is best. I think the latter is really what you need

Comment: @Ggalla1779 Yeah the logic is simple if you think about it. I am cracking my brains here with different code samples :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm

You need implementation of this, to be precise. :)